# c++ libtins build error

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm attempting the litbins build packet example over at http://libtins.github.io.

I've followed the install instructions and am able to `#include <tins/tins.h>` just fine.  The problem seems to be now in actually referencing its functions.  When trying to build this class:

```
#include <tins/tins.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace Tins;
int main() {

    NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface::default_interface();

    NetworkInterface::Info info = iface.addresses();

    EthernetII eth("77:22:33:11:ad:ad", info.hw_addr);

    eth /= IP("localhost", info.ip_addr);

    eth /= TCP(13, 15);

    eth /= RawPDU("I'm a payload!");

    PacketSender sender;

    sender.send(eth, iface);
}
```

I get this error:

```
cd '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `main':
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `Tins::NetworkInterface::default_interface()'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `Tins::NetworkInterface::addresses() const'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `Tins::EthernetII::EthernetII(Tins::HWAddress<6ul, unsigned char> const&, Tins::HWAddress<6ul, unsigned char> const&)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(char const*)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `Tins::IP::IP(Tins::IPv4Address, Tins::IPv4Address)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `Tins::TCP::TCP(unsigned short, unsigned short)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `Tins::RawPDU::RawPDU(std::string const&)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Tins::PacketSender::DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Tins::NetworkInterface::NetworkInterface()'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Tins::PacketSender::PacketSender(Tins::NetworkInterface const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `Tins::PacketSender::send(Tins::PDU&, Tins::NetworkInterface const&)'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Tins::PacketSender::~PacketSender()'
/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Tins::PacketSender::~PacketSender()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `Tins::EthernetII& Tins::operator/=<Tins::EthernetII>(Tins::EthernetII&, Tins::PDU const&)':
/usr/local/include/tins/pdu.h:537: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::inner_pdu(Tins::PDU*)'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `Tins::EthernetII::~EthernetII()':
/usr/local/include/tins/ethernetII.h:46: undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::EthernetII'
/usr/local/include/tins/ethernetII.h:46: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `Tins::IP::~IP()':
/usr/local/include/tins/ip.h:64: undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::IP'
/usr/local/include/tins/ip.h:64: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `Tins::TCP::~TCP()':
/usr/local/include/tins/tcp.h:79: undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::TCP'
/usr/local/include/tins/tcp.h:79: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `Tins::RawPDU::~RawPDU()':
/usr/local/include/tins/rawpdu.h:64: undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::RawPDU'
/usr/local/include/tins/rawpdu.h:64: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket' failed
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Netbeans is using c++11 , I've enabled c++11 support with the `-DLIBTINS_ENABLE_CXX11=1` and I've run `ldconfig` along with restarting the VM, same errors.

I've tried linking the class with `g++ main.cpp -o main -ltins` to get these errors -

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/tins/tins.h:60:0,
                 from main.cpp:14:
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:297:13: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     typedef std::function<void(const std::string&,
             ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:308:13: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     typedef std::function<void(const std::string&,
             ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:401:44: error: ‘handshake_captured_callback_type’ does not name a type
     void handshake_captured_callback(const handshake_captured_callback_type& callback);
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:412:34: error: ‘ap_found_callback_type’ does not name a type
     void ap_found_callback(const ap_found_callback_type& callback);
                                  ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:445:9: error: ‘handshake_captured_callback_type’ does not name a type
         handshake_captured_callback_type handshake_captured_callback_;
         ^
/usr/local/include/tins/crypto.h:446:9: error: ‘ap_found_callback_type’ does not name a type
         ap_found_callback_type ap_found_callback_;
         ^
```

Help appreciated.

EDIT

Following on from dvnguyen's answer below, linking my `main.cpp` with `g++ app.cpp -o app -ltins -std=c++11` solved the above issues, but now I'm left with the following errors -

```
cd '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o -lmain
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lmain
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket' failed
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tcppacket] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/oisin/NetBeansProjects/TCPPacket'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

I'm really clueless as to what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `undefined reference` message in the error log I can tell that you haven't added/linked the lib to your project. I don't know about your Netbean project setting, but if your use gcc, you can see an example [here](http://libtins.github.io/download/#using):

`g++ app.cpp -o app -ltins -std=c++11`

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've attempted this too - see updated question with log.

Comment: It's probably caused by C++11 type. I think this should work:

Comment: g++ app.cpp -o app -ltins -std=c++11

Comment: This works for linking, still the same error when building in NetBeans though.

Comment: You need to set the library linking and C++11 in your NetBeans project property. A quick Google search may give you some information.

Comment: OK so I set my linked file as a library and my `C++ Standard` in properties is set to `C++11`, resulting in same error as beginning minus reference errors.. clueless.

Comment: Anyway, I've run it from terminal and it works, so I guess my problem is with NetBeans.

Comment: I'm an eejit, I was pointing to the wrong lib for libtins.  thanks for your help.